# entering a new sentence without using <br> or <p>

Tags: html, line, paragraph, pre, page-break-inside

If there are a number of links on a webpage, is it possible to break onto a new line while the link is either fully on either side?
For example: This blog http://northskie.blogspot.com/ shows a series of links using the standard A HREF="http://www... "  etc  .
    But, you'll notice that on the first line, Chapin's Inferno appears on BOTH sentence line A,  AND line B.   This could easily be corrected by adding a BR, of course.  BUT, what if I'm working on a huge number of links, such as http://asmrluv.blogspot.com/ ?   Now, I'd prefer NOT to to simply add BR or P between each Breaking line.  Also note, many sites could be added to the list later.  This is why BR lines should be avoided here.

Can any code be implemented which automatically prevents a link from appearing on both lines?     (of course, adding a CLASS or ID would along with code would be acceptable).   I'm trying to avoid the problem of a link appearing halfway on one sentence, then on the next line as well.

Comment: HTML content wraps around its container. I'm not sure there is a way to prevent that...

Comment: There **was** the `<NOBR>` element but that has either been grandfathered out or is going to be in favor of a CSS `white-space:nowrap;` property.

Comment: The white-space:nowrap feature appears to create the desired effects which I'm seeking.    The white-space feature handles differently depending on whether simple text is written or A HREF links.   So, it seems to work perfectly with links.

Comment: This question has been correctly answered by Jeeped.   Now, I'm trying to figure out how to acknowledge on Stackoverflow the question as been resolved.